# regular expression for checking .css file

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna check the file is css file or not using regular expression.
I tried

```
new RegExp(".css$").test("a.css"); //true
```

but it is matching filename.acss which is correct.
I want regex to match a valid .css file only. I need following cases .

```
new RegExp(".css$").test("a.acss"); //false
new RegExp(".css$").test(".css"); //false
new RegExp(".css$").test("a.cssa"); //false
new RegExp(".css$").test("a.css"); //true
```

Comment: "match a valid .css file" do you mena that the file extention as a string is .css or the file is the right mime type?

Comment: regular expressions are overkill for this simple task. simply test if the ending of the string is ".css" and if the length of the file name is >= 4. more efficient!

Comment: I suggest re-reading some basic regexp tutorials. You'll quickly encounter the `.` character which matches anything, and needs to be escaped if you mean a real period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.`:  (The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline character.

You need to escape `.` by preceding `\` to match `.` literal.

```
var regex = /.\.css$/; // /\S+\.css$/; // /[\w\d]+\.css$/
regex.test("a.css");
```

**Exaples**

```js
var regex = /.\.css$/;

alert(regex.test("a.acss")); // false
alert(regex.test(".css")); // false
alert(regex.test("a.cssa")); // false
alert(regex.test("a.css")); // true
```

Comment: it is matching to regex.test(".css"); also . which I don't want

Comment: bro I want to avoid .css also . 2nd test must give false

Comment: Just use `.+\.css$` then. That requires at least one more character in front of the extension.

Comment: `\S+\.css$` will not work for file systems that allow white spaces in file names. To have a working regex that works with any characters allowed by a file system and any character set, use `.+\.css$`.

Comment: Downvoter, Can something be improved? Please add comment here

Comment: To be utterly and patently pedantic, there is no need for the `+`.

Comment: Re downvote, there are useful threads on meta on this topic, but in this case, consider that the question is "How do I write a regular expression to match the letter 'a'?" The best thing to do is downvote ("this question does not show any research effort") and move on. Eventually, the question will hopefully be closed or deleted. If you answer, and if your answer is upvoted or accepted, the question becomes harder to delete or close. Furthermore, by answering you are encouraging the posting of questions of an extremely rudimentary nature, which could be answered by a quick Google or doc scan.

Comment: @torazaburo Is that the criteria for downvote? I thought criteria for downvote is if answer is *not useful*.

Comment: Well, the basic criteria for downvote is "I feel like downvoting it", but one can make the case that an answer which promotes and encourages extremely poor questions is "not useful", I suppose.